# Invalid method declaration: "return type required" in constructor

Tags: java

My problem is here between `public` and `StudentInfo`:

```
public class Student_Database{
  public StudentInfo(int IDnum,String Name,String Year) {
    this.IDnum = IDnum;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Year = Year;       
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your class?

Comment: Do you want that to be a method or a constructor?

Comment: Please don't write "ALL CAPS STATEMENT" in your question. I've edited it for you this time.

Comment: public class Student_Database{}

Comment: @user3236941: please see edit to my answer.

Comment: The constructor and the class should have the same name.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to create a constructor, but the compiler doesn't see this as one. I'm guessing but likely your constructor name isn't exactly matching your class name. If so, fix this. Make them match -- the class name must ***exactly*** match that of the constructor, including spelling and capitalization.

As an aside, you'll want to learn and adhere to Java naming conventions, including giving all variables and parameters names that start with lower-case letters. So your field names should be idNum, name, and year.

---

**Edit**
You state that the class declaration is: `public class Student_Database{}`. If so, then the constructor should look like so:

```
public Student_Database(int IDnum,String Name,String Year)
{
    this.IDnum = IDnum;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Year = Year;       
}
```

Although better would be I think to keep it as StudentInfo, and have it look like:

```
public class StudentInfo {
  private int idNumber;
  private String name;
  private String year;

  public StudentInfo(int idNumber, String name, String year) {
     this.idNumber = idNumber;
     this.name = name;
     this.year = year;
  }

  // getters, setters, toString, equals override, hashCode override

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may want to create a method to set `StudentInfo`

```
public void setStudentInfo(int IDnum,String Name,String Year)
{
    this.IDnum = IDnum;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Year = Year;       
}
```

Comment: For original OPs benefit the convention in Java is that method names begin with lower case character. A verb to begin he method name would also help but that's up to you (zhenxiao hao) to communicate

Comment: @ Crowie Well, I just gave him a tip based on his question. cRowIe